# bitcoin-cli sendrawtransaction gives odd error 16

Tags: bitcoin-core, bitcoin-cli

When I submit the tx below with bitcoin-cli sendrawtransaction I get the error

16: mandatory-script-verify-flag-failed (Script evaluated without error but finished with a false/empty top stack element)

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

What's wrong with my tx?

Answer (score 1):

When a scriptSig/scriptPubKey executes, it's supposed to leave an element that evaluates to true on the top of the stack. Both of these are Pay to Public Key Hash inputs, so that means that OP_CHECKSIG failed for at least one of your inputs. Check the signatures.